# Deploy MS ACCESS driver to connect in ASP.NET (shared hosting)

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-access

I've tried to deploy a small website (ASP.NET) which is using an MS ACCESS 2010 db. Deploying the website on the server I get the following error:

The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
Connectionstring used : Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=path-to-db

MS Office is not installed on the server and neither is the Access Database engine. The website is runnin in a shared hosting environment, so I am not able to install office on that server, so may I somehow deploy the provider by dll's?

Is it possible to deploy the drivers needed for ASP.Net to connect to the database without having to run an installation on the server. As this is in a shared hosting environment, I am not able to install anything. Only fileupload by ftp.

Comment: What version of Windows is on the server? Also, does the application pool run as a 64Bit process? Many COM objects only work in 32 Bit.

Answer (score 1):

> so may I somehow deploy the provider by dll's?

No. Brutally speaking you fucked that up - you should have selected the provider with technology that you need, or should have (a lot more common) used SQL Server for development - Access is kind of rarely used in this environment.

Back to the drawing board, and this time make your homework properly.

Comment: We actually have the same issue. No way to use Access in a shared hosting environment? MDB is used from a 3rd party tool as a "file-type". So it's out of our hands.

Comment: No, not unless the shared hoster supports it. And a third party using access in 2014 is reckless - a good reason to tell that third party to go and party somewhere else. THis is not 1995.

Comment: It's a legacy system. Out of my control.

Comment: Put it on a machien you control - then you can install the drivers necessary. The legacy obviously now needs a virtual machine.

Comment: Yep, I was hopping there is a different solution.